# Having trouble querying JSON with Json.Net after converting from XML

Tags: c#, json.net, json-query

I have some XML which I convert to JSON by invoking this method:

```
public static string SerializeAsJson(string xml)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(xml)) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(xml));
    if (xml.StartsWith("{") && xml.EndsWith("}")) return xml;

    var doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(xml);

    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);
    return json;
}
```

Which returns this:

```
{
"?xml":{
    "@version":"1.0",
    "@encoding":"UTF-8"
},
"product":{
    "productname":{
        "#cdata-section":"Artisan Cook Processor - Onyx Black, 4.5 litres, Keep-warm function, Dishwasher-safe pot, Timer"
    },
    "productshortname":{
        "#cdata-section":"Artisan Cook Processor - Onyx Black"
    },
    "productshortdesc":{
        "#cdata-section":"Rethink the way you cook with the KitchenAid Artisan Cook Processor in stylish onyx black. The ultimate helping hand Create delicious meals in no time with this all-in-one, multifunctional food processor. It really can do everything you need to cook up a feast - chop, crush, blend, mix, steam, steam and fry to name a few of the 25 helpful functions. Additionally, this KitchenAid worktop cooker benefits from a clever StirAssist asset, which gently flips and stirs your ingredients, so they still have the �stirred-by-hand', home-cooked effect when combined together. Simplicity, control and precision Create elegantly simple meals for one or test yourself with a whole dinner party of treats from scratch with the Artisan Cook Processor . The KitchenAid really makes life in the kitchen easier � use the hinged lid to open your processor whilst it is working, to add ingredients as you go, reducing mess and saving you time. Uniquely stylish The 4.5 litre KitchenAid Artisan comes in stainless steel with the added benefit of ergonomic, comfortable handles and a hinged lid for easy opening. It is reliable, robust and easy to clean with dishwasher-safe parts, meaning you don't need to spend hours manually maintaining it. Premium details such as metal knobs, levels and a die-cast metal body make this KitchenAid a real focal point of the kitchen, particularly with its striking onyx black colouring. Included extras Along with your KitchenAid Artisan Cook Processor , enjoy the step-by-step and easy to follow recipes for cooking delicious meals in your KitchenAid Artisan Processor . If you are looking for a streamlined appliance that has multiple functions covered, consider the KitchenAid Artisan Cook Processor."
    },
    "producthtmldesc":{
        "#cdata-section":"<p>Rethink the way you cook with the KitchenAid <strong>Artisan Cook Processor</strong> in stylish onyx black.<br /> <br /> <strong>The ultimate helping hand</strong><br /> <br /> Create delicious meals in no time with this all-in-one, multifunctional food processor. It really can do everything you need to cook up a feast - chop, crush, blend, mix, steam, steam and fry to name a few of the 25 helpful functions.<br /> <br /> Additionally, this KitchenAid worktop cooker benefits from a clever StirAssist asset, which gently flips and stirs your ingredients, so they still have the �stirred-by-hand', home-cooked effect when combined together.<br /> <br /> <strong>Simplicity, control and precision</strong><br /> <br /> Create elegantly simple meals for one or test yourself with a whole dinner party of treats from scratch with the <strong>Artisan Cook Processor</strong>. The KitchenAid really makes life in the kitchen easier � use the hinged lid to open your processor whilst it is working, to add ingredients as you go, reducing mess and saving you time.<br /> <br /> <strong>Uniquely stylish</strong><br /> <br /> The 4.5 litre KitchenAid <strong>Artisan</strong> comes in stainless steel with the added benefit of ergonomic, comfortable handles and a hinged lid for easy opening. It is reliable, robust and easy to clean with dishwasher-safe parts, meaning you dont need to spend hours manually maintaining it.<br /> <br /> Premium details such as metal knobs, levels and a die-cast metal body make this KitchenAid a real focal point of the kitchen, particularly with its striking onyx black colouring.<br /> <br /> <strong>Included extras</strong><br /> <br /> Along with your KitchenAid <strong>Artisan Cook Processor</strong>, enjoy the step-by-step and easy to follow recipes for cooking delicious meals in your KitchenAid <strong>Artisan Processor</strong>.<br /> <br /> If you are looking for a streamlined appliance that has multiple functions covered, consider the KitchenAid <strong>Artisan Cook Processor. </strong></p>"
    },
    "productlongdesc":{
        "#cdata-section":"Rethink the way you cook with the KitchenAid Artisan Cook Processor in stylish onyx black. The ultimate helping hand Create delicious meals in no time with this all-in-one, multifunctional food processor. It really can do everything you need to cook up a feast - chop, crush, blend, mix, steam, steam and fry to name a few of the 25 helpful functions. Additionally, this KitchenAid worktop cooker benefits from a clever StirAssist asset, which gently flips and stirs your ingredients, so they still have the �stirred-by-hand', home-cooked effect when combined together. Simplicity, control and precision Create elegantly simple meals for one or test yourself with a whole dinner party of treats from scratch with the Artisan Cook Processor . The KitchenAid really makes life in the kitchen easier � use the hinged lid to open your processor whilst it is working, to add ingredients as you go, reducing mess and saving you time. Uniquely stylish The 4.5 litre KitchenAid Artisan comes in stainless steel with the added benefit of ergonomic, comfortable handles and a hinged lid for easy opening. It is reliable, robust and easy to clean with dishwasher-safe parts, meaning you don't need to spend hours manually maintaining it. Premium details such as metal knobs, levels and a die-cast metal body make this KitchenAid a real focal point of the kitchen, particularly with its striking onyx black colouring. Included extras Along with your KitchenAid Artisan Cook Processor , enjoy the step-by-step and easy to follow recipes for cooking delicious meals in your KitchenAid Artisan Processor . If you are looking for a streamlined appliance that has multiple functions covered, consider the KitchenAid Artisan Cook Processor."
    },
    "productsecondaryname":{
        "#cdata-section":"4.5 litres, Keep-warm function, Dishwasher-safe pot, Timer"
    },
    "brand":{
        "#cdata-section":"KITCHENAID"
    },
    "infostech":null,
    "refexternal":{
        "#cdata-section":"144626"
    },
    "infotech":{
        "#cdata-section":"[{\\"         Title\\":\\"OVERVIEW\\",
        \\"Priority\\":1,
        \\"Attributes\\":[
            {
            \\"Title\\":\\"Type\\",
            \\"Value\\":\\"Multicooker\\",
            \\"Priority\\":0
            },
            {
            \\"Title\\":\\"Power\\",
            \\"Value\\":\\"1500 W\\",
            \\"Priority\\":2
            },
            {
            \\"Title\\":\\"Capacity\\",
            \\"Value\\":\\"4.5 litres\\",
            \\"Priority\\":1
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        \\"Title\\":\\"FUNCTIONS\\",
        \\"Priority\\":2,
        \\"Attributes\\":[
            {
            \\"Title\\":\\"Number of programmes\\",
            \\"Value\\":\\"25\\",
            \\"Priority\\":4
            },
            {
            \\"Title\\":\\"Timer\\",
            \\"Value\\":\\"Yes\\",
            \\"Priority\\":8
            },
            {
            \\"Title\\":\\"Number of heat settings\\",
            \\"Value\\":\\"Up to 140�C\\",
            \\"Priority\\":7
            },
            {
            \\"Title\\":\\"Keep warm function\\",
            \\"Value\\":\\"Yes\\",
            \\"Priority\\":6
            },
            {
            \\"Title\\":\\"Programs\\",
            \\"Value\\":\\"- Boil- Fry- Stew- Steam- Puree- Dough\\",
            \\"Priority\\":5
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        \\"Title\\":\\"FEATURES\\",
        \\"Priority\\":3,
        \\"Attributes\\":[
            {
            \\"Title\\":\\"Digital display\\",
            \\"Value\\":\\"Yes\\",
            \\"Priority\\":10
            },
            {
            \\"Title\\":\\"Automatic shut-off\\",
            \\"Value\\":\\"Yes\\",
            \\"Priority\\":18
            },
            {
            \\"Title\\":\\"Dishwasher safe parts\\",
            \\"Value\\":\\"Yes\\",
            \\"Priority\\":17
            },
            {
            \\"Title\\":\\"Microwave safe pot\\",
            \\"Value\\":\\"No\\",
            \\"Priority\\":16
            },
            {
            \\"Title\\":\\"Oven safe pot\\",
            \\"Value\\":\\"No\\",
            \\"Priority\\":15
            },
            {
            \\"Title\\":\\"Number of tiers\\",
            \\"Value\\":\\"3\\",
            \\"Priority\\":14
            },
            {
            \\"Title\\":\\"Sound signal\\",
            \\"Value\\":\\"Yes\\",
            \\"Priority\\":12
            },
            {
            \\"Title\\":\\"Power indicator\\",
            \\"Value\\":\\"Yes\\",
            \\"Priority\\":11
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        \\"Title\\":\\"GENERAL\\",
        \\"Priority\\":4,
        \\"Attributes\\":[
            {
            \\"Title\\":\\"Colour\\",
            \\"Value\\":\\"Black\\",
            \\"Priority\\":20
            },
            {
            \\"Title\\":\\"Manufacturer's guarantee\\",
            \\"Value\\":\\"3 years\\",
            \\"Priority\\":26
            },
            {
            \\"Title\\":\\"Weight\\",
            \\"Value\\":\\"10.14 kg\\",
            \\"Priority\\":25
            },
            {
            \\"Title\\":\\"Dimensions \\",
            \\"Value\\":\\"411 x 314 x 342 mm (H x W x D)\\",
            \\"Priority\\":24
            },
            {
            \\"Title\\":\\"Power cord length\\",
            \\"Value\\":\\"1 m\\",
            \\"Priority\\":23
            },
            {
            \\"Title\\":\\"Power cord storage\\",
            \\"Value\\":\\"No\\",
            \\"Priority\\":22
            },
            {
            \\"Title\\":\\"Box contents\\",
            \\"Value\\":\\"- StirAssist- Egg whip- Dough blade- Multiblade- Upper and lower steam baskets with lid- Inner basket- Mini bowl and mini multiblade- Measuring cup- Free cookbook\\",
            \\"Priority\\":21
            }
        ]
    }
]   "},"   id":{
    "#cdata-section":"10136069"
},
"images":{
    "urlimage1":"https://brain-images-ssl.cdn.dixons.com/9/6/10136069/l_10136069.jpg",
    "urlimage2":"https://brain-images-ssl.cdn.dixons.com/9/6/10136069/g_10136069.jpg",
    "urlimage3":"https://brain-images-ssl.cdn.dixons.com/9/6/10136069/m_10136069.jpg",
    "urlimage4":"https://brain-images-ssl.cdn.dixons.com/9/6/10136069/s_10136069.jpg",
    "urlimage5":"https://brain-images-ssl.cdn.dixons.com/9/6/10136069/t_10136069.jpg",
    "urlimage6":"https://brain-images-ssl.cdn.dixons.com/9/6/10136069/u_10136069.jpg"
},
"images_alternate":{
    "urlimage1":"https://brain-images-ssl.cdn.dixons.com/9/6/10136069/t_10136069_003.jpg",
    "urlimage2":"https://brain-images-ssl.cdn.dixons.com/9/6/10136069/m_10136069_003.jpg",
    "urlimage3":"https://brain-images-ssl.cdn.dixons.com/9/6/10136069/s_10136069_003.jpg",
    "urlimage4":"https://brain-images-ssl.cdn.dixons.com/9/6/10136069/g_10136069_003.jpg",
    "urlimage5":"https://brain-images-ssl.cdn.dixons.com/9/6/10136069/l_10136069_003.jpg",
    "urlimage6":"https://brain-images-ssl.cdn.dixons.com/9/6/10136069/t_10136069_001.jpg",
    "urlimage7":"https://brain-images-ssl.cdn.dixons.com/9/6/10136069/m_10136069_001.jpg",
    "urlimage8":"https://brain-images-ssl.cdn.dixons.com/9/6/10136069/s_10136069_001.jpg",
    "urlimage9":"https://brain-images-ssl.cdn.dixons.com/9/6/10136069/g_10136069_001.jpg",
    "urlimage10":"https://brain-images-ssl.cdn.dixons.com/9/6/10136069/l_10136069_001.jpg",
    "urlimage11":"https://brain-images-ssl.cdn.dixons.com/9/6/10136069/t_10136069_006.jpg",
    "urlimage12":"https://brain-images-ssl.cdn.dixons.com/9/6/10136069/m_10136069_006.jpg",
    "urlimage13":"https://brain-images-ssl.cdn.dixons.com/9/6/10136069/s_10136069_006.jpg",
    "urlimage14":"https://brain-images-ssl.cdn.dixons.com/9/6/10136069/g_10136069_006.jpg",
    "urlimage15":"https://brain-images-ssl.cdn.dixons.com/9/6/10136069/l_10136069_006.jpg",
    "urlimage16":"https://brain-images-ssl.cdn.dixons.com/9/6/10136069/t_10136069_005.jpg",
    "urlimage17":"https://brain-images-ssl.cdn.dixons.com/9/6/10136069/m_10136069_005.jpg",
    "urlimage18":"https://brain-images-ssl.cdn.dixons.com/9/6/10136069/s_10136069_005.jpg",
    "urlimage19":"https://brain-images-ssl.cdn.dixons.com/9/6/10136069/g_10136069_005.jpg",
    "urlimage20":"https://brain-images-ssl.cdn.dixons.com/9/6/10136069/l_10136069_005.jpg",
    "urlimage21":"https://brain-images-ssl.cdn.dixons.com/9/6/10136069/t_10136069_002.jpg",
    "urlimage22":"https://brain-images-ssl.cdn.dixons.com/9/6/10136069/m_10136069_002.jpg",
    "urlimage23":"https://brain-images-ssl.cdn.dixons.com/9/6/10136069/s_10136069_002.jpg",
    "urlimage24":"https://brain-images-ssl.cdn.dixons.com/9/6/10136069/g_10136069_002.jpg",
    "urlimage25":"https://brain-images-ssl.cdn.dixons.com/9/6/10136069/l_10136069_002.jpg",
    "urlimage26":"https://brain-images-ssl.cdn.dixons.com/9/6/10136069/t_10136069_004.jpg",
    "urlimage27":"https://brain-images-ssl.cdn.dixons.com/9/6/10136069/m_10136069_004.jpg",
    "urlimage28":"https://brain-images-ssl.cdn.dixons.com/9/6/10136069/s_10136069_004.jpg",
    "urlimage29":"https://brain-images-ssl.cdn.dixons.com/9/6/10136069/g_10136069_004.jpg",
    "urlimage30":"https://brain-images-ssl.cdn.dixons.com/9/6/10136069/l_10136069_004.jpg"
},
"universe":{
    "#cdata-section":"Household Appliances"
},
"universeid":"35",
"category":{
    "#cdata-section":"Small kitchen appliances"
},
"categoryid":"336",
"market":{
    "#cdata-section":"Small cooking appliances"
},
"marketid":"3155",
"segment":{
    "#cdata-section":"Multicookers"
},
"segmentid":"31992",
"MPN":{
    "#cdata-section":"000000859792415020"
},
"EAN":"5413184100599",
"color":null,
"weight":"1"
}
}
```

The only part I am interested in is `infotech` so I try to get that part using a path query of `"product.infotech.#cdata-section"`, like this:

```
var json = JObject.Parse(response);
var products = json.SelectToken(path);
```

Which gives me this:

```
{
    [
        {
            "Title":"OVERVIEW",
            "Priority":1,
            "Attributes":[
                {
                "Title":"Type",
                "Value":"Multicooker",
                "Priority":0
                },
                {
                "Title":"Power",
                "Value":"1500 W",
                "Priority":2
                },
                {
                "Title":"Capacity",
                "Value":"4.5 litres",
                "Priority":1
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Title":"FUNCTIONS",
            "Priority":2,
            "Attributes":[
                {
                "Title":"Number of programmes",
                "Value":"25",
                "Priority":4
                },
                {
                "Title":"Timer",
                "Value":"Yes",
                "Priority":8
                },
                {
                "Title":"Number of heat settings",
                "Value":"Up to 140�C",
                "Priority":7
                },
                {
                "Title":"Keep warm function",
                "Value":"Yes",
                "Priority":6
                },
                {
                "Title":"Programs",
                "Value":"- Boil- Fry- Stew- Steam- Puree- Dough",
                "Priority":5
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Title":"FEATURES",
            "Priority":3,
            "Attributes":[
                {
                "Title":"Digital display",
                "Value":"Yes",
                "Priority":10
                },
                {
                "Title":"Automatic shut-off",
                "Value":"Yes",
                "Priority":18
                },
                {
                "Title":"Dishwasher safe parts",
                "Value":"Yes",
                "Priority":17
                },
                {
                "Title":"Microwave safe pot",
                "Value":"No",
                "Priority":16
                },
                {
                "Title":"Oven safe pot",
                "Value":"No",
                "Priority":15
                },
                {
                "Title":"Number of tiers",
                "Value":"3",
                "Priority":14
                },
                {
                "Title":"Sound signal",
                "Value":"Yes",
                "Priority":12
                },
                {
                "Title":"Power indicator",
                "Value":"Yes",
                "Priority":11
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Title":"GENERAL",
            "Priority":4,
            "Attributes":[
                {
                "Title":"Colour",
                "Value":"Black",
                "Priority":20
                },
                {
                "Title":"Manufacturer's guarantee",
                "Value":"3 years",
                "Priority":26
                },
                {
                "Title":"Weight",
                "Value":"10.14 kg",
                "Priority":25
                },
                {
                "Title":"Dimensions ",
                "Value":"411 x 314 x 342 mm (H x W x D)",
                "Priority":24
                },
                {
                "Title":"Power cord length",
                "Value":"1 m",
                "Priority":23
                },
                {
                "Title":"Power cord storage",
                "Value":"No",
                "Priority":22
                },
                {
                "Title":"Box contents",
                "Value":"- StirAssist- Egg whip- Dough blade- Multiblade- Upper and lower steam baskets with lid- Inner basket- Mini bowl and mini multiblade- Measuring cup- Free cookbook",
                "Priority":21
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to cast that as `IList<JObject>` but no matter what I try, I just get an error. Can someone help me?

P.S., if I look at the value of products, it shows an array:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that the value of `product.infotech.#cdata-section` is a JSON string; it is not an array (yet).  You can see this in the debugger screenshot: the `Type` is listed as `String` (not `Array`).  Probably the original XML had JSON in that tag.  When the whole thing was converted to JSON, the already existing JSON was escaped, which is why all the extra backslashes are present.  So, to get the value back to a usable form, you need to re-parse that part:

```
var json = JObject.Parse(response);

// get the escaped JSON as a string
var productsJson = (string)json.SelectToken("product.infotech.#cdata-section");

// re-parse it to a JArray
var productsArray = JArray.Parse(productsJson);

// Now you can iterate over the array to access the JObjects within it
foreach (JObject item in productsArray)
{
    ...
}
```